# Is Facebook batch request photo upload with no_story possible?

Tags: facebook, upload, request, photo, batch-processing

Is it?

Uploading works like a charm, but I don't want it to show up on timeline or feed.
I've tried adding no_story to each request, and to the $params which is commented out in following code:

```
 foreach ($data['Ad']['Media'] as $medium) {
            $file = $medium['tmp_name'];
            $req = array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'relative_url' => '/me/photos',
                'message' => $data['Ad']['title'],
                'attached_files' => 'file' . $count,
                'no_story' => 1 //Also tried 'true'                     
            );

            //add this request to batch
            $batch[] = json_encode($req);
            $params['file' . $count] = '@' . realpath($file);
            $count++;
        }//foreach
        $params['batch'] = '[' . implode(',', $batch) . ']';
        //$params['no_story'] = true;
```

### Edit ##

See comment below.

Answer (score 0):

i know you may not need the answer any more, but i was facing same issue , and after a lot of try and error i figured it out so i will post the answer may be some one face this issue again

```
$req = array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'relative_url' => '/me/photos',
            'attached_files' => 'file' . $count,
            'body' => 'no_story=1'                      
        );
```